# How can I use "?" instead of if statement?

Tags: c#, if-statement

```
if (entity.ScdDept == "") 
  command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SCD_DEPT", DBNull.Value);
else 
  command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SCD_DEPT", entity.ScdDept);

if (entity.LeaveDate == DateTime.MaxValue) 
   command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LEAVE_DATE", DBNull.Value);
else  
   command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LEAVE_DATE", entity.LeaveDate);
```

It works like that. But I want to use `?` instead of `if`

I tried like that:

```
var result = entity.scdDept = " " ? command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SCD_DEPT", DBNull.Value :  entity.ScdDept;
```

This doesn't work, but I need the one line solution.

Comment: search for "ternary operator".. however I'd stick to the normal IF syntax for the sake of readability of code

Comment: Do you mean `entity.scdDept == " "` instead of `entity.scdDept = " "`?

Comment: You're missing a "=" character: `var result = entity.scdDept == ""`

Comment: command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SCD_DEPT", string.IsNullOrEmpty(entity.ScdDept)?DBNull.Valur :  entity.ScdDept)

Comment: Note the core of your question but still a recommended read: https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/

Comment: I know ternary operators. but I can't do this example.
Also It's true to entity.scdDept==" " but my error doesnt fix

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what you're looking for:

```
   command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SCD_DEPT", entity.ScdDept == "" ? DBNull.Value : (object) entity.ScdDept);
   command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LEAVE_DATE", entity.LeaveDate == DateTime.MaxValue ? DBNull.Value : (object) entity.LeaveDate);
```

Comment: I tried that  but I took an error  Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between 'System.DBNull' and 'string'

Comment: Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between 'System.DBNull' and 'System.DateTime'

Comment: That is because the compiler can not implicitly convert DateTime to object.

Comment: @OnurcanŞimşek Add a cast to object like I added to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a helper function if you're going to be using this a lot

```
static object ValueOrDbNull(object value) => value ?? DBNull.Value;

static object ValueOrDbNull(bool isValid, object value) => isValid ? value : DBNull.Value;
```

Use case:

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SCD_DEPT", ValueOrDbNull(entity.ScdDept == "", entity.ScdDept));
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LEAVE_DATE", ValueOrDbNull(entity.LeaveDate == DateTime.MaxValue, entity.LeaveDate));
```